# Doctrine: Relating a model to itself using a link table, like "This event is related to to the following other events"

Tags: php, database-design, doctrine, doctrine-1.2, object-relational-model

So in English, the relationship would sound like "This event is related to to the following other events".

My first instinct is to create an `EventEvent` model, with a `first_event_id` field and a `second_event_id` field. Then I would define the following two relationships in the `Event` model:

```
$this->hasMany('Event as FirstRelatedEvents', array('local' => 'first_event_id', 'foreign' => 'second_event_id', 'refClass' => 'EventEvent'));
$this->hasMany('Event as SecondRelatedEvents', array('local' => 'second_event_id', 'foreign' => 'first_event_id', 'refClass' => 'EventEvent'));
```

But I would rather not have to use two relationships on the `Event` model. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in the manual: [Equal Nest Relations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/defining-models%3arelationships%3ajoin-table-associations%3aself-referencing-nest-relations%3aequal-nest-relations)